# SQL Server Management Studio 2008R2 with SQL Server 2017-- compatibility?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

I am working on a project where I will be provisioned a SQL Server 2017 database server. However, the only version of SQL Server Management Studio available to me is 2008R2. I could request a newer version but this may take 1-2 months before it is finally installed on my machine.

Am I going to run into compatibility issues? Are there any database settings in SQL Server 2017 I would need to set in order to use this?

I am pretty unfamiliar with the MS suite of database tools so sorry for my ignorance in this! Thanks

**In response to comments:**

I have a managed system so I am not able to install or run software that has not been "approved". I have tried the portable version of VS Code but that did not work for me. I am going through the process of requests SSMS 2017 but like I said in the question this will not be available for 1-2 months. In the meantime will SSMS 2008 work?

Comment: You can [download SSMS 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) from MS for free now. Why would you have to wait 1-2 months for it? And why would a company that will provision you with a 2017 server installation make you wait for the management tools to work with it?

Comment: Try this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This person is not going to be able to install SSMS from a download. There are a few alternative tools to try that _might_ work for someone without admin access. You might be able to install a portable version of VS Code with a SQL Add in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable. There's also SQL Operations Studio but I think that will probably need admin access. When you are in a situation with a heavily constrained SOE the first thing to do is try hacking it :)

Comment: @KenWhite Government work where the server is provisioned by a partner organization, but client support is governed by us. It is just as frustrating as it sounds.

Comment: You have my sympathy. I work in a similar situation, it seems, but at least I can get the tools i need to work. Seems pretty sad to be able to get a database provisioned for development but not be able to get the DBMS maker's official tools for working with it at the same time. Good luck. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As unlikely as this may be, I happen to have two, and only two, versions of SSMS installed on my machine; 2008R2 and 2017. I'm in the midst of an upgrade project.

I opened SSMS 2008R2 and was to connect to and generally poke around on a SQL Server 2017 server and the related databases. I didn't do anything too complicated (a few `SELECT` statments & an `UPDATE`), but they worked. The objects I expected to be visible were visible. And I didn't have to do anything to make it work. It just worked.

Mostly.

Except that every time I right clicked on a table, an error box opened with this message:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

But if I hit the `OK` button, the box cleared and the desired right click menu opened and functioned. That will get irritating, but if you poke around in the Options menu, there might be a way to make it stop. I invested no minutes trying to do that.

At the very least, you should be able to work while you're waiting for your upgrade.

For what it's worth, I work for a government contractor and have the same level of security constraints you do, so I feel your pain.

Comment: Thanks Eric, super helpful! I've already put in a request to get SSMS 2018 installed so I'm glad I'll at least be able to get some use out of it over the coming months despite a few quirks

Comment: Glad it helped! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to run sqlcmd, which would have been installed with SQL Server 2008R2.  I was able to connect from sqlcmd to a SQL Server 2017 Docker container (external/internal ports 1433).  I did not encounter any errors/warnings when creating a database and table, and running some light queries.

Interestingly, I was **unable** to connect to the same server using SSMS 2008R2.  Perhaps the protocol used or the security required (e.g., TLS 1.2) for the underlying connection was different.  Clearly it works based on Eric Brandt's results.